# How can i separate web.config httpErrors with HttpResponseMessage HttpStatusCode

Tags: asp.net-mvc, error-handling

I am developing an application with asp.net mvc

I am sending ajax post request.

I get 500 status codes when an error occurs during operation.

This scenario is correct, but the code in the web.config file redirect to the error page.

This my codes

```
    public class ErrorHandler : FilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
    {
        public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
        {
            var response = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response;

            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;

            response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

            filterContext.Result = new JsonResult
            {
                Data = new {

                    success = false
                },

                JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
            };
        }
    }
```

Web.Config

```
<httpErrors existingResponse="Replace" defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL" errorMode="Custom">
      <remove statusCode="500"/>
      <error statusCode="500" path="/common/error" responseMode="Redirect"/>
    </httpErrors>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A Little Suggestion**

You should not set the `response.StatusCode` to  `HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError` all the time when there is an exception. Try and be more specific so you are not always returning 500. If you return a different, more specific error code, then according to your `web.config` a redirect will not be sent. For example, if the error is because the ajax requested a user with a specific id and that user does not exist, then return error code 404.

---

Now to fix your issue, you can do this:

```
if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
{
    CallbackException error = new CallbackException();
    error.message = errorMessage;
    error.isCallbackError = true;
    error.stackTrace = stackTrace;

    JSONSerializer Serializer = new JSONSerializer();
    string result = Serializer.Serialize(error);

    var response = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response;
    response.ContentType = ControlResources.STR_JsonContentType;

    response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
    response.StatusCode = 500;
    response.Write(Result);
    HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
}
else
{
    // The code in your answer goes here
}
```

Please see [this](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2009/Apr/29/IIS-7-Error-Pages-taking-over-500-Errors) article for more details if interested.